# Macbook keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, macbook

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 14.04 on my Macbook 3,1. It worked well until today. The internal keyboard doesn't work properly anymore. Most keys don't work at all, while a few produce the wrong characters. For example, the keys J, K and L produce the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

It's not a hardware issue, in Mac OS everything is still fine. My external keyboard also works correctly.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't know why, but the problem was solved by pressing F6 twice.

Comment: @Close voters - this is not unreproducible, I just reproduced it. It didn't go away on it's own ^^ he pressed F6!

Comment: @New close voters - this is perfectly clear - he accidentally enabled the number pad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by OP in comments

> I don't know why, but the problem was solved by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> twice.

FYI, this is because the keyboard has a number pad built in. <kbd>F6</kbd> disables this, and means you can type your letters rather than numbers.

[image]

> Press the Caps Lock key. num. (F6) to activate the keypad.

<sup>[Source](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/11200-macbook-pro-keyboard-numpad)</sup>

Comment: I don't have a Macbook Pro and there are no numbers on the keys, hence my confusion. I don't know how the numpad function got activated, I cannot reactivate the function with any of the shortcuts in the source. But I don't care, I don't need that anyhow. :-)